# Spring Security 5 and jwk-set-uri with Authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Well, I have a URL to get public-keys but this URL require a Bearer Token, so I have the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://myauth-server.com/keys.jwt
```

And my Security Configuration Class:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
        authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers("/customers/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().anonymous()
    ).oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
}
```

But when I try to make a request I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
```

And my pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>7.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I really don't know if this error is because my "keys.jwt" URI require some authentication or another reason.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved with the following:

```
 @Bean
    public NimbusJwtDecoder nimbusJwtDecoder(){
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        rest.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders().setBearerAuth(myJwt);
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        });
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUri)
                .restOperations(rest).build();
    }
```

Comment: where do you get the `myJwt`` ?

Comment: Yes, where do you get `myJwt` from?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [lanhelles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60869224/13315230) answer:

you should inject http servlet request

```
    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Bean
    public NimbusJwtDecoder nimbusJwtDecoder() {
    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
        request.getHeaders().setBearerAuth(httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).split(" ")[1]);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    });
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("domain/realms/realm_name/protocol/openid-connect/certs")
            .restOperations(restTemplate).build();
}
```

Extract auth token that clients sent in header and then put it into NimbusJwtDecoder